# Youtube ActionBar Tabs like

Tags: android, layout, tabs, actionbarsherlock, adapter

I'm pretty familliar with `ActionBarSherlock` and `ViewPager` but what i would like to do is having something between `Tabs` and `ActionBar`.

```
[-------ActionBar------------------]
[-------SomeLayout-----------------]
[-------Tabs-----------------------]
[-------TabContent/ViewPager-------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[----------------------------------]
[-------SomeFooter/pub-------------]
```

Is there some other library i could use to achieve that ?

Comment: You can use a tabhost, just be prepared for a decent amount of work.

Comment: Yes with TabHost it'll be too long. That's why i'm trying to find some bypass ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `PagerTabStrip`, `TabPageIndicator` (from the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com) library), [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/), or something similar for the tabs for your `ViewPager`. You are then welcome to put something else above those via a vertical `LinearLayout`.

Comment: This is a fine answer Thanks ! I'll take a look at it. For those who are interrested i found an application on the play market that groups a lot of libraries : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos